# Transaction Aborted

Tags: java, jpa

my code is this..

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPU")
private EntityManager em;
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void registerManufactuerer(Manufacturer manufacturer) throws Exception {
    if (manufacturer.getId() != null) {
        for (Product product : manufacturer.getProducts()) {
            em.persist(product);
            em.remove(product);
        }
        em.persist(manufacturer);
        throw new Exception("Successfully registered");
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Registration is not possible");
    }
}
```

when i run the project i got an exception....that is...

```
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.
at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:473)
at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:852)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5114)
... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: com.model.Product[ id=1 ].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.discoverUnregisteredNewObjects(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.calculateChanges(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:695)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1482)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3135)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(JTASynchronizationListener.java:68)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:435)
    ... 65 more
```

actually...what is reason?

Comment: possible duplicate of [transaction rolled back?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441272/transaction-rolled-back)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is what the error message tells you:

> During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: com.model.Product[ id=1 ]

Your product references another entity that was not persisted yet and the relation does not define a persist cascade. Thus the id of that new entity is not found on the database and thus your product can't be persisted yet.

Most probably it is the manufacturer, so persist the manufacturer first.

Btw, why do you first persist a product and immediately delete it again?

Comment: there is one to many relationship in manufacturer to product....i like to know this condition ,that persist and remove....

Comment: @Shemil what are you doing posting the [same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441272/transaction-rolled-back) question again? Do I get bonus points for answering your previous question and correctly guessing the name of the related entity?? ;)

Comment: @Shemil you don't have a many-to-one on `Product`as well? Without that you'd have to use a mapping table and I doubt you use that. As I said, you can persist manufacturer and product independently, just persist manufacturer _first_.